# Angular 2 get rid of nested subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular

Could any of you tell me how I can get rid of nested subscriptions like the following piece of code? I need to get the values out of the subscription to keep it more organised but if I use a global variable it will be undefined because the subscription did not yet receive the value.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  if (params) {
    this.room = params['room'];
    this.service.func(o).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.localstore = data;
        this.title = 'Current store ' + this.localstore;
        this.service.send(b, {
           data: data
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What's your goal? You want to chain observables and execute the second `subscribe` only after the first, and may be use data from the first inside the second?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain observable by analogy with regular promises, you can use [**`flatMap`**](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator for that:

```
this.activatedRoute.params
  .flatMap((params: Params) => {
    if (params) {
      this.room = params['room'];
      return this.service.func(o);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.localstore = data;
      this.title = 'Current store ' + this.localstore;
      this.service.send(b, {
         data: data
      });
    }
  });
```

This way every next block will be executed right after the previous one. Pay attention, that you have to use `flatMap` for every block, except the last one - it should contain the regular `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [".flatMap"](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) function on observables. They are very similar to a Promises ".then".

So your code would look something like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.flatMap((params: Params) => {
  if (params) {
    this.room = params['room'];
    return this.service.func(o);
  }
  return null;
).subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.localstore = data;
    this.title = 'Current store ' + this.localstore;
    this.service.send(b, {
      data: data
    });
  }
});
```

The flat map allows you to wait until the observable sends a result. So you can use flat maps to chain multiple async requests together.